# How to order data twice. But make the firts orderBy ineffective

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get last 100 posts from database and than order them by likecount or another property and output only 5 of them, that way I will discover most liked 5 posts or viewed, or reported out of last 100 posts. What I tried so far is like below:

```
$lastHundredPost = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(100);
$post = $lastHundredPost->orderBy('likecount', 'desc')->take(2)->get();
```

this does not disable first `orderBy` property.

> Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get result from the first query, use collections:

```
$lastHundredPost = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(100)->get();
$post = $lastHundredPost->sortByDesc('likecount')->take(2);
```

Comment: but this will order data eather for id or like count.

Comment: @Nikonah I'm sorry, but it's not very clear. Could you tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to get the second set of data from the first one, use collections as I've shown in the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I want to get last 100 post and than order them by likecount, and than output 5 most liked out of last 100 posts.

Comment: the thing you shared did not work, it still shows most recent post as priority

Comment: @Nikonah the first line will take 100 latest records from DB. The second line will use the loaded data (collection) and sort these records by `likecount` (desc) and will take 2 top records.

Comment: sortByDesc() is the way to go,

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to execute sql query and get 100 row, and then use `sortBy`method of your collection.

```
$lastHundredPost = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(100)->get();

$lastHundredPost->sortBy('likecount')->take(2);
```

Another idea is to use `orderByRaw`:

```
$posts = Post::orderByRaw('likecount DESC, id DESC')->take(2)->get();
```

Comment: it still orders rows primerely for the id and that likecount